# I have 2 versions of the same shell script. ASCII wise they are Identical, but only one executes correctly

Tags: shell-script

I have 2 version of the same shell script file. ASCII wise they are Identical (Used Notepad++ Compare Plugin), but only one executes correctly.

I ran `FC /B` on the windows command line to compare them at a binary level it it says they are different.

how can this happen?

Note: this is a Raspbian shell script that I wrote.

Output of the FC command

```
Comparing files start-NotWorking.sh and START-WORKING.SH
0000000B: 0D 0A
0000000C: 0A 23
0000000D: 23 4C
0000000E: 4C 61
0000000F: 61 75
00000010: 75 6E
00000011: 6E 63
00000012: 63 68
00000013: 68 20
00000014: 20 4C
00000015: 4C 6F
00000016: 6F 67
00000017: 67 20
00000018: 20 46
00000019: 46 69
0000001A: 69 6C
0000001B: 6C 65
0000001C: 65 20
0000001D: 20 52
0000001E: 52 65
0000001F: 65 61
00000020: 61 64
00000021: 64 65
00000022: 65 72
00000023: 72 20
00000024: 20 57
00000025: 57 65
00000026: 65 62
00000027: 62 20
00000028: 20 53
00000029: 53 65
0000002A: 65 72
0000002B: 72 76
0000002C: 76 65
0000002D: 65 72
0000002E: 72 0A
0000002F: 0D 5F
00000030: 0A 49
00000031: 5F 50
00000032: 49 3D
00000033: 50 22
00000034: 3D 24
00000035: 22 28
00000036: 24 68
00000037: 28 6F
00000038: 68 73
00000039: 6F 74
0000003A: 73 6E
0000003B: 74 61
0000003C: 6E 6D
0000003D: 61 65
0000003E: 6D 20
0000003F: 65 2D
00000040: 20 49
00000041: 2D 29
00000042: 49 22
00000043: 29 0A
00000044: 22 65
00000045: 0D 63
00000046: 0A 68
00000047: 65 6F
00000048: 63 20
00000049: 68 22
0000004A: 6F 49
0000004B: 20 50
0000004C: 22 20
0000004D: 49 61
0000004E: 50 64
0000004F: 20 64
00000050: 61 72
00000051: 64 65
00000052: 64 73
00000053: 72 73
00000054: 65 3A
00000055: 73 20
00000056: 73 24
00000057: 3A 5F
00000058: 20 49
00000059: 24 50
0000005A: 5F 22
0000005B: 49 0A
0000005C: 50 74
0000005D: 22 61
0000005E: 0D 69
0000005F: 0A 6C
00000060: 74 6F
00000061: 61 6E
00000062: 69 20
00000063: 6C 2D
00000064: 6F 66
00000065: 6E 20
00000066: 20 2F
00000067: 2D 75
00000068: 66 73
00000069: 20 62
0000006A: 2F 64
0000006B: 75 72
0000006C: 73 69
0000006D: 62 76
0000006E: 64 65
0000006F: 72 2F
00000070: 69 6C
00000071: 76 6F
00000072: 65 67
00000073: 2F 73
00000074: 6C 2F
00000075: 6F 72
00000076: 67 65
00000077: 73 63
00000078: 2F 65
00000079: 72 6E
0000007A: 65 74
0000007B: 63 2D
0000007C: 65 6C
0000007D: 6E 6F
0000007E: 74 67
0000007F: 2D 2E
00000083: 2E 20
00000084: 6C 2F
00000085: 6F 75
00000086: 67 73
00000087: 20 62
00000088: 2F 64
00000089: 75 72
0000008A: 73 69
0000008B: 62 76
0000008C: 64 65
0000008D: 72 2F
0000008E: 69 6C
0000008F: 76 6F
00000090: 65 67
00000091: 2F 73
00000092: 6C 2F
00000093: 6F 6C
00000094: 67 6F
00000095: 73 67
00000096: 2F 73
00000097: 6C 2D
00000098: 6F 69
00000099: 67 6E
0000009A: 73 66
0000009B: 2D 6F
0000009C: 69 72
0000009D: 6E 6D
0000009E: 66 61
0000009F: 6F 74
000000A0: 72 69
000000A1: 6D 6F
000000A2: 61 6E
000000A3: 74 2F
000000A4: 69 2A
000000A5: 6F 2E
000000A6: 6E 6C
000000A7: 2F 6F
000000A8: 2A 67
000000A9: 2E 20
000000AA: 6C 2F
000000AB: 6F 75
000000AC: 67 73
000000AD: 20 62
000000AE: 2F 64
000000AF: 75 72
000000B0: 73 69
000000B1: 62 76
000000B2: 64 65
000000B3: 72 2F
000000B4: 69 6C
000000B5: 76 6F
000000B6: 65 67
000000B7: 2F 73
000000B8: 6C 2F
000000B9: 6F 6C
000000BA: 67 6F
000000BB: 73 67
000000BC: 2F 73
000000BD: 6C 2D
000000BE: 6F 77
000000BF: 67 61
000000C0: 73 72
000000C1: 2D 6E
000000C2: 77 69
000000C3: 61 6E
000000C4: 72 67
000000C5: 6E 73
000000C6: 69 2F
000000C7: 6E 2A
000000C8: 67 2E
000000C9: 73 6C
000000CA: 2F 6F
000000CB: 2A 67
000000CC: 2E 20
000000CD: 6C 2D
000000CE: 6F 62
000000CF: 67 20
000000D0: 20 22
000000D1: 2D 24
000000D2: 62 5F
000000D3: 20 49
000000D4: 22 50
000000D5: 24 3A
000000D6: 5F 38
000000D7: 49 30
000000D8: 50 22
000000D9: 3A 20
000000DA: 38 2D
000000DB: 30 61
000000DC: 22 20
000000DD: 20 26
000000DE: 2D 0A
000000DF: 61 23
000000E0: 20 45
000000E1: 26 6E
000000E2: 0D 64
000000E3: 0A 20
000000E4: 23 4C
000000E5: 45 61
000000E6: 6E 75
000000E7: 64 6E
000000E8: 20 63
000000E9: 4C 68
000000EA: 61 20
000000EB: 75 4C
000000EC: 6E 6F
000000ED: 63 67
000000EE: 68 20
000000EF: 20 46
000000F0: 4C 69
000000F1: 6F 6C
000000F2: 67 65
000000F4: 46 52
000000F5: 69 65
000000F6: 6C 61
000000F7: 65 64
000000F8: 20 65
000000F9: 52 72
000000FA: 65 20
000000FB: 61 57
000000FC: 64 65
000000FD: 65 62
000000FE: 72 20
000000FF: 20 53
00000100: 57 65
00000101: 65 72
00000102: 62 76
00000103: 20 65
00000104: 53 72
00000105: 65 0A
00000106: 72 65
00000107: 76 78
00000108: 65 70
00000109: 72 6F
0000010A: 0D 72
0000010B: 0A 74
0000010C: 65 20
0000010D: 78 44
0000010E: 70 49
0000010F: 6F 53
00000110: 72 50
00000111: 74 4C
00000112: 20 41
00000113: 44 59
00000114: 49 3D
00000115: 53 3A
00000116: 50 30
00000117: 4C 0A
00000118: 41 58
00000119: 59 20
0000011A: 3D 2D
0000011B: 3A 6E
0000011C: 30 6F
0000011D: 0D 63
0000011E: 0A 75
0000011F: 58 72
00000120: 20 73
00000121: 2D 6F
00000122: 6E 72
00000123: 6F 20
00000124: 63 2D
00000125: 75 73
00000126: 72 20
00000127: 73 30
00000128: 6F 20
00000129: 72 2D
0000012A: 20 64
0000012B: 2D 70
0000012C: 73 6D
0000012D: 20 73
0000012E: 30 26
0000012F: 20 0A
00000130: 2D 6D
00000131: 64 6F
00000132: 70 6E
00000133: 6D 6F
00000134: 73 20
00000135: 26 2F
00000136: 0D 75
00000137: 0A 73
00000138: 6D 62
00000139: 6F 64
0000013A: 6E 72
0000013B: 6F 69
0000013C: 20 76
0000013D: 2F 65
0000013E: 75 2F
0000013F: 73 61
00000140: 62 70
00000141: 64 70
00000142: 72 2F
00000143: 69 73
00000144: 76 74
00000145: 65 61
00000146: 2F 72
00000147: 61 74
00000148: 70 2E
00000149: 70 65
0000014A: 2F 78
0000014B: 73 65
0000014C: 74 26
0000014D: 61 0A
FC: start-NotWorking.sh longer than START-WORKING.SH
```

Comment: In `Notepad++`, select `View => Show Symbol => Show All characters`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is probably written in DOS format, where line endings are carriagereturn+newline, whereas Unix format is just one newline character. The shell doesn't understand the carriagereturn and sees that as just another character such as a letter or dot. Hence you get errors.

Using Notepad++ (a Windows program) will probably ignore the different line endings. If you really want to see the differences use

```
cmp -l file1 file2
```

This will compare each byte, outputting differing byte values in octal.

You can also compare the output of

```
cat -vet file1
```

and

```
cat -vet file2
```

carriagereturn is shown as `^M`, tabs as `^I`. End of line is `$`.

Edit: your `FC` output shows the bytes as hexadecimal. `0D` is the carriagereturn, `0A` is newline.

To convert from DOS to Unix format, you can use the `dos2unix` command (you may need to install the `dos2unix` package first).

```
dos2unix -o file1
```